# get the name of the current $_GET variable

Tags: php, arrays, get

I want to know what URL user has accessed.  For example, if user accessed:

> index.php?register

it will echo '1'.

```
if (isset($_GET))
{
    switch ($_GET)
    {
        case "register":
            echo 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't do anything, why? How do you get the name of the first GET element?

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` to see what is there.

Comment: You are case-ing where `$_GET = register` which is never true. You need to foreach through the array in key=>value pairs to check where `switch($key) { case "register" `

Comment: `array_keys`, `$_REQUEST`, `isset($_GET['register'])`, `array_key_exists($_GET, 'register')`... tried any of those?

Comment: if you want to do it on-fly, try: array_keys($GET)

Comment: `$_GET` is an array.  You need to loop through it and read the key(s).

Comment: 1. `$_GET` is always set. 2. `$_GET` is an array and can't be used as `string`. 3. You may want to have: `index.php?act=register` and use `switch ($_GET['act']) {...}`. 4. 3 is fast solution but awful.

Answer (score 4):

`$_GET` is an array. You'd need to place that switch statement inside a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
    switch ($k) {
        case 'register':
            echo 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Also, the `$_GET` superglobal is *always* set – there's no need for `if (isset($_GET)) {`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array_keys()` to get the keys for each $_GET, then use the `0 index` to determine what you wanted to do with the first key:

```
if($_GET){
    $keys = array_keys($_GET);
    switch ($keys[0]){
        case "register":
            echo 1;
        break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is a superglobal array.  It's always set, and always an array.

If you know that `register` will *always* be the 1st GET element, then you can do this:

```
reset($_GET);
switch (key($_GET)){
    case "register":
        echo 1;
    break;
}
```

<sub>Docs for `key()`: http://php.net/key</sub>

Comment: What if something before `switch` moved pointer?

Comment: @PLB: I'm assuming the pointer of `$_GET` wasn't moved but, I added `reset($_GET);` :-)

Answer (score -3):

$_GET is an associative array, so it's structured in `key=value` elements

you can either use this URL: `index.php?page=register` with this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    switch ($_GET['page'])
    {
        case "register":
            echo 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

OR with this URL `index.php?register` use this code:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'register':
            echo 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is **no reason** to do this...

Comment: You can do `index.php?register`.  It just makes `$_GET['register']` a blank string.

Comment: @Neal Must you downvote everything you see?

Comment: @Simon_eQ if it is wrong? Yes.

Comment: @Neal It seems like, you don't know what wrong means either..

Comment: @Simon_eQ: it's not wrong, it's just an other way to do!

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ I don't know what you mean. I was referring to Neal's comments, that he deleted. Not yours.